# Mysterious "watson" function

Tags: actionscript-3

I found an undocumented function in toplevel.as (where things like trace and Infinity are defined) called watson, here is it's definition:

```
public function watson (n:int) : Boolean;
```

And yet i can find no documentation, blog posts, or stack exchange questions about this function. If i referance the definition in my code it throws an error

```
1120: Access of undefined property watson.
```

Does anyone have any information about this function?

Comment: Why would you care about this function ?

Comment: because i thought i knew most of that are of the library, and not knowing what this super mysterious function does just bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other mysterious entity in toplevel.as is Bugzilla (source: http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4-game-programming/topics/233329), I'm fairly sure this refers to [Dr. Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Watson_%28debugger%29), and was used at some point during the process of developing the program to interact with Dr. Watson.

I have no evidence other than the name, and the fact that it's in the same file as another debugging function, and is also a dummy function. That's where I think it came from, I don't think you will be able to use it.

Comment: hmm, that seems pretty likely since they both take an int and return a boolean.